# MongoDB concurrent access on insert

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, morphia

I'm using MongoDB with a Play Framework application using Morphia. I'm building a quizz system using the following elements :

```
public class MyProduct extends MongoEntity {
    @Embedded
    public Questionnaire questionnaire;
}

public class Questionnaire extends MongoEntity {
    @Reference
    public Set<Question> questions;

    @Embedded
    public Map<String, Answer> answers;
}
```

I have lots of reads on `MyProduct`.
The `Question` contains the question itself and the possible answers.
The `Answer` contains the user answer for the given questions (the key of the Map is the user id).

My problem is how can I handle concurrent access when the users answer to the questions. Even if the answers are stored in the same document, all the users will be able to answer **at the same time** ?

If not, should I put my answers as different documents in a dedicated collection ?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't decided by how you program but instead by the concurrency features of MongoDB, currently MongoDB has a database level lock for those kind of operations. I am unsure I get your question, you mean that all users should be able to write to a single document at the same time? How would that work?

Comment: Yes, each time a user answers to the questionnaire, a new "line" is added to the Map of answers. If I embed the answers in the questionnaire it means that all the users can edit the same document at the same time, right ? The other solution is to create a dedicated collection for the answers. With that, each time a user answers, a new "document" is created in this collection.
What is the more efficient way ? I can also use MySQL. The most important for me, is to be able to determine the order of the answers.

Comment: I think you are looking at this from a client side point of view since that is where it most makes sense. Yes, client side you can give the users (all of them) the ability to answer and edit at the same time. As to which is most efficient (coming back to server-side, i.e. the db itself) that would depend on how much traffic you are getting to that subdocument (map) of answers and exactly how you wish to query them (analytics for example). Embedding it makes operations atomic but can make it harder to do complex queries

Comment: I will have a lot of writes in a short period of time (10-15minutes) and after that, no more answers because I will close the questionnaire. So if I understand, if I embed the document, if I have lots of writes, it can lead too poor read performance ?

Comment: I don't see the problem in writing concurrency, because all the users add a new line to the document, and that could be resolved with simple addToSet update operation (I don't know how is it resolved in your framework, but surely it's available). Although in reading that could be a problem if you're going to do aggregation queries (as I guess) at the same time as the users write, but I think it also can be solved by reading in a secondary instance.

Comment: It would mainly effect write performance since your creating a bottleneck in your IO, it could effect read performance as well of course but there are numerous fail safes for ensuring that reads get a place.

Comment: I would think its effect on reads, for aggregation would not be significant due to the concurrency rules that makes write subside for read operations, so even though the lock is writer greedy it does subside and since reads are concurrent (only writes can be done once a time) writing is where you will find the bottle neck here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally created a different collection to handle `QuestionnaireAnswer` documents referenced to the questionnaire. I think it will be easier to query.